# Кроссплатформенный  C#-код

Tags: c#, windows, linux

Есть ли средства, позволяющие написать (а потом запустить)  кроссплатформенный код на C#? Если да, то какие?

Comment: Мобильные платформы тоже интересны.

Answer (score 4):

Для линукса - Mono. Консольные программы, созданные в винде, довольно неплохо запускаются ею. Сам баловался. Обратно не пробовал.

Что-то слышал про C# на iOS.

Правда, программы на C# в линях большая редкость.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант один единственный и очень хороший - используете любую IDE для разработки, далее под OC Windows собираете *нативно*, под linux - с помощью [**Mono.**](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Конечно, Mono отстает в плане некоторых возможностей от нативного C# runtime и, очевидно, не успевает за обновлениями, однако разница, в общем-то, незначительна. *И да, Mono - opensource проект.*

Answer (score 2):

Mono. Даже с окнами приложения в Mono работают довольно стабильно. Даже код переписывать ни в одном месте не пришлось.

Советую по почитать статью и комментарии к ней - [Выпуск MonoDevelop 2.8 — интеграция с XCode 4, поддержка iOS 5 и другое](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mono/129855/) :)

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы писали на WinForms? Или что-то друоге?

Comment: да, именно WinForms

Comment: дополнил свой ответ, думаю поможет Вам оценить преимущества и недостатки

Answer (score 2):

Проблема .NET в том, что на всех платформах (кроме Windows, там .NET Framework) придётся устанавливать Mono, а он достаточно большой по размеру.

Кстати, у меня программы, написанные на C#, даже на телефоне запускаются, только при открытии файлов ошибки. Работает даже Windows Forms, только мелко всё, неудобно пользоваться. У меня ОС Maemo (это Linux), установлен Mono.

Comment: А под макось тоже Mono?

Comment: Да, по крайней мере, если верить странице по ссылке выше.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибки при открытии файлов возникают при использовании Windows-разделителей пути "\".

Есть два способа преодолеть это:

1. Использовать "/", как в Unix-системах (Windows это переваривает без скрипа)
2. Использовать [`System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx)
3. Использовать [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) для собирания пути из имён каталогов