# Совместимость программ под Windows c Linux и Mac

Tags: c#, linux, windows, macos, кроссплатформенность

Пишу программу на Windows Forms C# в которой используются хуки API. На винде все работает конечно, но интересует вопрос о совместимости с другими ОС, будет ли все работать так же? Есть ли списки классов c# которые 100% не работают под Linux и Mac или работают частично ?

Comment: практически дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/45024/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485705/178576)

Comment: Т.е. нужно поставить компилятор mono и заново пересобрать проект на нем?